# Efficiently finding rows following a subset of rows of a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, shift

How can one find efficiently (i.e. vectorized solution) rows which follow a subset of rows of a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame?

For a single index, it seems one could use `pandas.Index.shift`.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# original data-frame
t = pd.DataFrame(data={'i1':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                       'i2':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                       'x':[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.]})
t.set_index(['i1','i2'], inplace=True)
t.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(t)

# subset of rows
t2 = t.loc[(slice(None),slice(1,1)),:]
print(t2)

# example of *not efficient* solution (i.e. not vectorized)
t3 = t.iloc[ [t.index.get_loc(v)+1 for v in t2.index] ]
print(t3)
```

```
# original DataFrame
          x
i1 i2      
0  0    1.0
   1    2.0
   2    3.0
   3    4.0
1  0    5.0
   1    6.0
   2    7.0
   3    8.0
2  0    9.0
   1   10.0
   2   11.0
   3   12.0

# subset of rows
          x
i1 i2      
0  1    2.0
1  1    6.0
2  1   10.0

# expected solution
          x
i1 i2      
0  2    3.0
1  2    7.0
2  2   11.0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Yuca, could you please clarify? `help(t.index.id)` gives "AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'id'"

Comment: yup, working on a good link for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the following rows of some arbitrary subset, you can do it by creating a mask:

```
mask = pd.Series(False, index=t.index)
mask[t2.index] = True
```

Then you can indexing `t` with the shifted mask:

```
t3 = t.loc[mask.shift(1).fillna(False)]
# and maybe:
t4 = t.loc[mask.shift(2).fillna(False)]
```

However, this just sounds like an XY problem. What do you really want? If you only want to conveniently indexing on the second level of multiindex, you should try `IndexSlice`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
t2 = t.loc[idx[:,1],:]
t3 = t.loc[idx[:,2],:]
```

Comment: Thank you: the solution works correctly. Unfortunately, in pandas, operations like `mask[t2.index] = True` are very slow. My impression is that internally they are not vectorized. Too bad, since I find myself in need to do those very frequently.